# ¿Cuál sería una equivalente de -just hear me out- en castellano?

Tags: traducción, conversación

Quiero saber una frase para responder cuando alguien te interrumpa, y solo quieres decir lo que quieres decir.

Un amigo mío de Colombia sugirió la frase **"solo escúchame"**.

Me gustaría saber otras frases posibles que no son tan obvias.

He puesto un ejemplo a continuación para que lo entendáis mejor. Gracias de antemano:

> Juan: Lo tendré en cuenta. Escucha, ¿Me haces un favor? Es que María
>   tiene ante sí el mismo destino grandioso que el elegido...
>
> Miguel: Otra vez con esa mierda...
>
> Juan: (just hear me out)

Comment: `escucha coño` es informal y autoritario...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Solo escúchame***, la frase más usual completa es ***solo escúchame un momento***.

O también ***ya, pero escúchame***.

Oído en España...

Answer (score 10):

La opción que te propuso tu amigo es totalmente válida y podrías usarla con múltiples ligeras variaciones, como por ejemplo:

> ¡Tú escucha!, ¡Primero escucha!, ¡Escúchame!, etc...

También existen otras opciones como:

> ¡Atiende!, ¡Hazme caso!, ¡Espera!, etc...

Sin embargo, la que en mi opinión es la mejor opción, y la que yo usaría para traducir `hear out` en este caso, sería:

> **¡Déjame terminar!** o **¡Déjame acabar!**

---

Por otra parte, déjame indicarte que en el diálogo que escribiste, en la pregunta `¿Me haces un favor?`, no deberías usar la `M` mayúscula, ya que la pregunta viene precedida de una coma `,`. Recuerda que el símbolo de interrogación `¿` no provoca que la siguiente palabra se escriba con mayúscula...

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina diríamos solamente

> Escuchame

me parece mucho más natural. Aunque depende del lugar obviamente.

También es muy común acompañar esto con gestos, indicándole a la otra persona que espere. Es decir por ejemplo abrir la mano y moverla ligeramente de forma horizontal, queriendo indicar un

> Espera, Calmate

para que la otra persona se dedique a escuchar lo que tenés para decir.